# Why does my app behave differently on mobile than on desktop?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, reactjs

I created a menu using React. The menu should have a "Logged in" and "Logged out" state. It works perfectly on normal and mobile sized browser window on a desktop. However, for some reason when I open the site on my phone at first it's in "Logged out" state, after I log in, it's in "Logged in" state and after that if I click on Log Out the browser just refreshes but the menu stays in "Logged In" state. Why is that? How could I change the menu to "Logged Out" state on log out?

Code related to menu (phone version):

```
function BarAndMenu(props) {
const [hamburger, setHamburger] = useState(false);
const handleDismissMenuAndLogOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("userIdLoggedIn");
    localStorage.removeItem("userNameLoggedIn");
    window.location.reload();
    setAnchorEl(undefined);
  };

const toggleHamburger = () => {
    setHamburger(!hamburger);
  };

const userNameLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("userNameLoggedIn");
return (
<div className="toolBar">
<button onClick={toggleHamburger} className="hamburger">
   {hamburger ? <Close /> : <MenuIcon />}
</button>
</div>
 <ul style={{
          display: window.innerWidth <= 680 && hamburger ? "block" : "none"
      }}
      className="mobileMenu">
        <Link to="/about" className="link" onClick={toggleHamburger}>
          <li>About</li>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/myTickets" className="link" onClick={toggleHamburger}>
          <li>MyTickets</li>
        </Link>
        {userNameLoggedIn ? (
          <>
            <Link to="/pages" className="link" onClick={toggleHamburger}>
              <li>{userNameLoggedIn}</li>
            </Link>
            <li onClick={handleDismissMenuAndLogOut} className="pointer">
              Log out
            </li>
            <Link to="/cards" className="link" onClick={toggleHamburger}>
              <li>Cards</li>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/settings" className="link" onClick={toggleHamburger}>
              <li>Settings</li>
            </Link>
          </>
        ) : (
          <li>{fbContent}</li>
        )}
</ul>
```

Where fbContent is a FacebookLoginButton (works correctly).
Site can be found at tiket.hu.

Comment: Perhaps the issues are not related. One thing that I noticed (and it's a bad practice) you are defining item into localStorage as soon as the user click on facebook login button. So If I close Facebook Tab I am logged in for the website whit this values inside the local storage userIdLoggedIn:undefined and userIdLoggedIn:undefined.
Wait the facebook login callback to set this parameters.

Comment: @StefanoBucci So, I added an if clause for this case: if (response.userID && response.name) {
    localStorage.setItem("userIdLoggedIn", response.userID);
    localStorage.setItem("userNameLoggedIn", response.name);
  }
It solves the problem you described, but the original problem is not solved.